# Prove that the image of a set is closed and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

Let $f:A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ where $A$ is closed and $f$ continuous in $A$. Prove that $D \subseteq A$ is bounded then $\overline{f(D)}$ is closed and bounded

We know that $\overline{f(D)}$ always is closed but I think maybe using Heine-Borel Theorem we want to show that $\overline{f(D)}$ is compact I woul appreciate any advice.

Comment: If you are not convinced by the answer posted below, try interacting with the answerer to get your doubts cleared. If you are satisfied, consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick mark button next to the answer. Doing so will award reputation points both to you and the answerer for taking the time out to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\overline D\subset\overline A=A$. Besides, since $D$ is bounded, $\overline D$ is bounded too. So, $\overline D$ is a compact subset of $A$. Therefore, $f\left(\overline D\right)$ is compact too, and so it is bounded. In particular, $f(D)$ is bounded, and so, $\overline{f(D)}$ is bounded too. Sinse it is a closure, it is also a closed set.